# Just noticed a flaw in my JavaScript quiz. I need assistance in fixing it

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, multidimensional-array

I recently discovered a bug in my JavaScript quiz by accident. It's a multiple choice quiz. I clicked on one of the answers. Then I kept clicking submit through the questions until the quiz was done. Instead of saying that I got 1 out of 15 questions right it said I got like 6 of 15 right, even though I left the other questions blank. This error in calculation only happens when I keep clicking submit after choosing an option. Any assistance is appreciated.

```js
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
 ["What does HTML stand for?", "High Tech Markup Language", "Hyper Text Multiple Listing", "Hyper Text Markup Language", "C"],
 ["What does CSS stand for?", "Computer Software Supervisor", "Cascading Stylesheets", "Computer Software Systems", "B"],
 ["What aspect of a website does JavaScript control?", "the behavior", "the structure", "the design & layout", "A"],
 ["What are media queries for?","They give the programmer access to covert media files.", "They make websites function well and look great on multiple devices like tablets and smartphones.", "They're a set of javascript libraries...like jquery.", "B"],
 ["The two categories of elements in html are block and...", "outline", "flatline", "inline", "C"],
 ["Which data type gives a value of true or false?", "character", "boolean", "integer", "B"],
 ["How do you write a comment in CSS?", "/* */", "//", "just write it out..", "A"],
 ["Java was developed by which company?", "Netscape", "Sun Microsystems", "Enron", "B"],
 ["Which gets more priority in CSS?", "class attribute", "element", "id attribute" ,"C"],
 ["PHP is a _________ language.", "server-side", "client-side", "westside", "A"],
 ["What does API stand for?", "Application Program Interface", "Apple Programs Iphones", "Advanced Programming Institute", "A"],
 ["Wordpress is a ...", "Content Management Device", "Content Manipulating Stylesheet", "Content Management System", "C"],
 ["Which of these is NOT a real programming language?", "C", "CSS", "JavaScript", "B"],
 ["In an HTML document it's best to store javascript in the ____ of the page.", "head", "bottom of the body", "top of the body", "B"],
 ["Bootstrap was built at which popular social media site?", "Twitter", "Facebook", "Instagram", "A"]
];
function _(x) {
 return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion() {
 test = _("test");
 if(pos >= questions.length){
  test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
  _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
  pos = 0;
  correct = 0;
  return false;
 }
 _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
 question = questions[pos][0];
 chA = questions[pos][1];
 chB = questions[pos][2];
 chC = questions[pos][3];
 test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
 test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
 test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
 test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>";
 test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
 choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
 for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
  if(choices[i].checked){
   choice = choices[i].value;
  }
 }
 if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
  correct++;
 }
 pos++;
 renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
```

```css
body {
 background: #f5f5f5;
}
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
header {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 190px;
 background-color: firebrick;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-left: black solid 1px;
 border-right: black solid 1px;
 
}
h1 {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 top: 65px;
 font-size: 3em;
 font-family: cooper;
}
h2 {
 position: relative;
 top: 30px;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
}
h3 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2em;
}
h5 {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 position: relative;
 top: 110px;
}
p {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
section {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 700px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: white;
 border-left: black solid 1px;
 border-right: black solid 1px;
}
#center {
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
}
#test {
 color: black;
 border: #000 1px solid;
 padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
 background-color: white;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 position: relative;
 top: 100px;
}
footer {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 250px;
 background-color: #003366;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-left: black solid 1px;
 border-right: black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Web Developer Quiz</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div="it">
 <h2 id="test_status"></h2>
 <div id="test"></div>
 <button><a href="index.html"></a></button>
 </div>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? The problem is clearly-stated, the code is nicely-formatted, and the question is well-defined.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of your `renderQuestion()` function, you should reset your `choice` variable

```
function renderQuestion() {
    choice = undefined;
    test = _("test");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the variable `choice` inside the `checkAnswer()` function instead of globally on the first line of your code. So make your global declarations look like this:

```
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
```

and then add it `checkAnswer()` like this:

```
function checkAnswer(){
  var choice;
...
```